# How can i create Bottom Navigation Bar with Floating Menu option?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomappbar

I want create bottom navigation bar with floating menu.Please help me,Thankyou[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `BottomAppBar`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676948/7666442

Comment: Thankyou, I want above mentioned design not like that,I have tried lot of way but it can't supported me.can you please help me to complete this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an android library to do the following work.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7732

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, I have already tried this .But I'm unable to implement  floating menu in the last item of bottom navigation bar.